# Setting custom data for block in layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, custom-block, data

I'm trying to set some custom data for my block in `local.xml`:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" template="custom.phtml">
            <action method="setCustomData"><string>Sample data</string></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

I would now assume that I can access this data in my `custom.phtml` template like this:

```
echo $this->getCustomData;
// or 
echo $this->getData('custom_data');
```

But none of the above works and I can't figure out way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer which was rather silly, the block needs to have a name for this to work:

```
<cms_index_index>
  <reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="core/template" name="custom" template="custom.phtml">
        <action method="setCustomData"><string>Sample data</string></action>
    </block>
  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```